# How to get last redirect URL in Spring WebClient

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty, spring-webclient

A client that follows redirects can be created as follows:

```
WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                        HttpClient.create().followRedirect(true)
                ))
```

After invoking a `HEAD` request on a URL, how can the final `Location` header be retrieved? In other words, how can we get the final URL redirected to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that `HttpClient#followRedirect(true)` enables the redirection.
However there is also `HttpClient#followRedirect(BiPredicate<HttpClientRequest,HttpClientResponse>)`, here you can control more precisely when you want to redirect and in addition to this you have always access to the response and the `Location` header, so in any time you will know to which location there will be a redirection.
More info [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.html#followRedirect-java.util.function.BiPredicate-) and [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html#_auto_redirect_support)

For example

```
        WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                        HttpClient.create().followRedirect((req, res) -> {
                            System.out.println(res.responseHeaders().get("Location"));
                            return HttpResponseStatus.FOUND.equals(res.status());
                        })
                ))
```

Comment: I came across this specific method but wasn't sure if the predicate gets called after every HTTP redirect, or just after the first HTTP call and then puts it on "autopilot" for the rest of the redirection chain.

Comment: After every redirect