# Follow redirection with cookies using WebFlux

Tags: java, netty, spring-webflux

I am using WebFlux with netty to make third party calls for my spring boot app. A post request with form parameters is made on client's provided url and client responds with 302 status and a location. The code I have written below is able to follow redirections but doesn't send cookies with it which is causing subsequent redirections to fail.

1. WebFlux config

```
@Bean
public WebClient webClient() {

    ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
        .codecs((configurer) -> {
          configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Encoder(new Jaxb2XmlEncoder());
          configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Decoder(new Jaxb2XmlDecoder());
        }).build();

    exchangeStrategies.messageWriters().stream()
        .filter(LoggingCodecSupport.class::isInstance)
        .forEach(writer -> ((LoggingCodecSupport) writer)
                            .setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(Boolean.TRUE));

    return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()
                .followRedirect(true)
                .secure()))
            .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
            .build();
}
```

2. Post Request

```
private <T> Mono <String> buildPostRequest(MultiValueMap <String, String> formData, String postUrl) {
    return client.post()
              .uri(postUrl)
              .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))
              .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
              .retrieve()
              .bodyToMono(String.class);
}
```

Comment: you ca use the `HttpClient#followRedirect(BiPredicate<HttpClientRequest,HttpClientResponse>)` function and specify more specific what you want to do during a redirect. You can extract the cooke from the response and place it in the next request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468043/how-to-get-last-redirect-url-in-spring-webclient